How to show image which is uploaded by gallery in asp.net through ajax by web method
I want to show image which I uploaded from gallery.
Here is my code,
<asp:Image Height="420px" Width="580px" runat="server" ID="img_Product" CssClass="col-md-2 control-label labelfont"></asp:Image>            

Here is my ajax code,
$(document).ready(function () {        
    var productValue = <%=Session["StockId"] %>;
    var Data = JSON.stringify({ productId: productValue });
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "Image.aspx/GetImageByStockId",
        data: Data,
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function (data) {
            if (data.d.Image == null) {
                alert("Sorry, No Image Found...!!!");                    
            }
            else {
                /*$("#img_Product").attr("src", data.d.Image);*/

                var base64String = data.d.Image; // Assuming data is returned as { "d": "base64string" }
                var img = document.getElementById('<%= img_Product.ClientID %>');
                img.src = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + base64String; // Adjust MIME type if needed
            }
        },
        error: function (xhr, status, error) {
            alert(error + status + xhr);
        }
    });
});

Here is my webmethod code,
[WebMethod]
public static ImageModel GetImageByStockId(int productId)
{
    Services service = new Services();
    ImageModel imageModel = new ImageModel();
    string qrySelImage = "Select * from tbl_StockRunning where StockId = " + productId + "";
    DataTable dtSelImage = new DataTable();
    dtSelImage = service.GetDataTable(qrySelImage);
    if (dtSelImage.Rows[0]["DesignImage"].ToString() != "")
    {
        if (dtSelImage.Rows[0]["DesignImage"].ToString() != "")
        {
            byte[] pic = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(dtSelImage.Rows[0]["DesignImage"].ToString());
            var data = (byte[])(dtSelImage.Rows[0]["DesignImage"]);
            //imageModel.Image = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + Convert.ToBase64String(data);
            imageModel.Image = Convert.ToBase64String(data);
        }
    } else
    {
        imageModel.Image = null;
    }
    return imageModel;
}

Now as per the code, while I am uploading image through camera then that image is showing perfectly in asp:image but while I am uploading picture from gallery then the image is not showing in asp:image.
Any issue in code?
